# how to make an alert box display over other activities

Tags: android

Suppose i am having an activity (let's say activity1) and i have given a command for doing some long process. Mean while i am starting another activity (activity2), during this time if the activity1 finishes the process and shows the result in an alert box, then how can i make this alert box of activity1 appear over activity2? What i have noticed is that, the alert box of activity1 is only visible when i move back to activity1. Is there any way to do this? Ignore if the question is irrelevant, as i am just a beginner in android.

Answer (score 0):

Before using two activity, you have to save the state of the activity and restore the another activity while come front. This is easily done by `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` method. Please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Comment: What i want to know is that, suppose i am running a thread or async task in activity1 and this process continues. While this is in progress i am working on another activity. Meanwhile if the thread in first activity completes, then i want to inform it to the user with the help of the alert box. I want this alert box appear over activity2